# Replace inches and other quotes in CSV, when not followed or preceded by comma

Tags: php, regex

I am parsing a CSV-file with `fgetcsv`. I got a CSV-export from a Magento installation. However, it is not parsable. Here is one problematic line of such an export:

> 200000,Samsung Galaxy S2,$399.00,8806085359376,null,Free ground shipping,New,In Stock,Samsung,"Vivid‧Fast‧Slim The new GALAXY SII Plus makes your life even smarter! 4.3" SUPER AMOLED Plus The 4.3" SUPER AMOLED Plus display goes a step beyond the already remarkable SUPER AMOLED to provide enhanced readability, a slimmer design, and better battery consumption for the best viewing value of any smartphone. Full-Touch Display Size: 4.3" Resolution: 480 x 800pixel Platform Operation Platform: Android v4.1 (Jelly Bean) TOUCHWiZ v4.0 User Interface (upto 7 pages widget desktop) Band^ UMTS(850 / 900 / 1900 / 2100MHz)+ Battery Capacity: 1650mAh",Mobile > Manufacturer > Samsung,

The problem is the usage of `"` in the file as short hand for `inch` and other occasions.

I am looking for a RegEx for `preg_replace`ing every double quote which is not followed by or preceded by a comma. However, my RegEx knowledge is bad and I cannot create a working expression.
This is what I think is quite near the solution, but I cannot make it work:

```
private static function _fixQuotesInString($string)
{
    return preg_replace('/(?<!,)"|"(?!,)/', '&quot;', $string);
}
```

As I, with my limited knowledge, would read it, i'd say: If you found a double quote, check whether it is not preceded with a comma nor followed by a comma, and if so, replace it with ".
However, experience has shown that it does not.

When you post a solution, it'd be nice if you could add a "spoken explanation" of the RegEx, so I can grasp it.

Comment: What do you do with this text: "excellent occasion, 4.3", samsung"

Comment: Looking at this, this is fairly hard to fix as the export obviously doesn't adhere *at all* to how CSV should look like. Wouldn't it be an easier option to fix the problem at the source?

Comment: @boisvert This worst case will break it anyway. I just want to make the best of a bad job. If under no circumstances recoverable, the user will be asked to fix his export.
Fixing the source will not be possible. Older Magentos export like this and many people use it.
I just ask for RegEx to circumvent walking through every char, noting if it is a " and appling rules to enclosed or not-enclosed special chars.

Comment: I agree with @Joey. Your only sane solution is to contact the people supplying you with the data and get them to fix their output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex will replace both `,"` and `",` because neither meet both of the alternation conditions simultaneously.  Instead, you can just use `(?<!,)"(?!,)` which requires the quote to be surrounded on *neither* side by a comma.

Note that there are still potential problems with the solution in case of `"` being followed by a comma legitimately, so you should look into fixing this problem at its source.

Comment: +1 for the "look at source" comment. Unescaped d-quotes in csv export is not valid input.

Comment: You are right with getting down to the root of the trouble, however I want to make this as resistant against badly formatted CSV as possible. I do lots of checks if the detected formatting really works.
If unrecoverable, the user will be asked to change his export settings. Only very few users will upload files as bad as the example at the top.
Your solution works and replaces the right, quotes, I could even follow your explanation.
I will leave this open a short time if there is anyone who has the ultimate parsing solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

## Description

If you're looking to simply parse each of the comma separated fields which may or  may not be surrounded by double quotes you could use this regex:

`(?:^|,)("?)(.*?)\1(?=,(?!\s)|$)`

[image]

Group 2 gets assigned each of the comma separated values. If the value is opened by a quote then a close quote followed by a `,` not followed by a space, or end of line is required to close the string.

## PHP Code Example:

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/(?:^|,)("?)(.*?)\1(?=,|$)/ims',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200000
            [1] => ,Samsung Galaxy S2
            [2] => ,$399.00
            [3] => ,8806085359376
            [4] => ,null
            [5] => ,Free ground shipping
            [6] => ,New
            [7] => ,In Stock
            [8] => ,Samsung
            [9] => ,"Vivid‧Fast‧Slim The new GALAXY SII Plus makes your life even smarter! 4.3" SUPER AMOLED Plus The 4.3" SUPER AMOLED Plus display goes a step beyond the already remarkable SUPER AMOLED to provide enhanced readability, a slimmer design, and better battery consumption for the best viewing value of any smartphone. Full-Touch Display Size: 4.3" Resolution: 480 x 800pixel Platform Operation Platform: Android v4.1 (Jelly Bean) TOUCHWiZ v4.0 User Interface (upto 7 pages widget desktop) Band^ UMTS(850 / 900 / 1900 / 2100MHz)+ Battery Capacity: 1650mAh"
            [10] => ,Mobile > Manufacturer > Samsung
            [11] => ,
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => "
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200000
            [1] => Samsung Galaxy S2
            [2] => $399.00
            [3] => 8806085359376
            [4] => null
            [5] => Free ground shipping
            [6] => New
            [7] => In Stock
            [8] => Samsung
            [9] => Vivid‧Fast‧Slim The new GALAXY SII Plus makes your life even smarter! 4.3" SUPER AMOLED Plus The 4.3" SUPER AMOLED Plus display goes a step beyond the already remarkable SUPER AMOLED to provide enhanced readability, a slimmer design, and better battery consumption for the best viewing value of any smartphone. Full-Touch Display Size: 4.3" Resolution: 480 x 800pixel Platform Operation Platform: Android v4.1 (Jelly Bean) TOUCHWiZ v4.0 User Interface (upto 7 pages widget desktop) Band^ UMTS(850 / 900 / 1900 / 2100MHz)+ Battery Capacity: 1650mAh
            [10] => Mobile > Manufacturer > Samsung
            [11] => 
        )

)
```

## Simple Replace

Because your source text is comma separated and the comma delimiters will not have any surrounding space to resolve the issue with `"excellent occasion, 4.3", samsung"` you could use

Regex: `(?<!,)(")(?!,\S)`   Replace with nothing

## PHP Code Example:

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
echo preg_replace('/(?<!,)(")(?!,\S)/ims','',$sourcestring);
?>

$sourcestring after replacement:
200000,Samsung Galaxy S2,$399.00,8806085359376,null,Free ground shipping,New,In Stock,Samsung,"Vivid‧Fast‧Slim The new GALAXY SII Plus makes your life even smarter! 4.3 SUPER AMOLED Plus The 4.3 SUPER AMOLED Plus display goes a step beyond the already remarkable SUPER AMOLED to provide enhanced readability, a slimmer design, and better battery consumption for the best viewing value of any smartphone. Full-Touch Display Size: 4.3 Resolution: 480 x 800pixel Platform Operation Platform: Android v4.1 (Jelly Bean) TOUCHWiZ v4.0 User Interface (upto 7 pages widget desktop) Band^ UMTS(850 / 900 / 1900 / 2100MHz)+ Battery Capacity: 1650mAh",Mobile > Manufacturer > Samsung,
```

Comment: Wow, this is ultra. Will ship this out in a following version of the CSV parser. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :)